# Getting Error while using if-else condition in Jmockit @Test method

Tags: java, jmockit

I am using Jmockit for functional testing for that in one test method i am using if-else condition like below

```
@Ignore
@Test(expected = CoreServiceException.class)
public final void setExpectationsForOrchestration( @Mocked final int type,
        @Mocked final Object request,
        @Mocked final String responseFile) throws Exception{


        new NonStrictExpectations() {

        {
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            File obligationResponseList = new File(mockDataDir
                + responseFile);
            FileReader xmlReader = new FileReader(
                obligationResponseList);
            if (type == 1) {
            orchestrationInstance
                .retrieveServiceObligationResponseByServiceObligationRequest(
                    (ServiceObligationRequest) request,
                    (AppContext) any);
            } else if (type ==2) {
            orchestrationInstance
                .retrieveServiceObligationEntitlementResponseByServiceObligationEntitlementRequest(
                    (ServiceObligationEntitlementRequest) request,
                    (AppContext) any);
            } else if (type == 3) {
            orchestrationInstance
                .retrieveServiceObligationHeaderOfferResponseByServiceObligationProductRequest(
                    (ServiceObligationProductRequest) request,
                    (AppContext) any);
            }
            else if (type == 4) {
            orchestrationInstance
                .retrieveServiceObligationCustomerDocumentByServiceObligationRequest(
                    (ServiceObligationRequest) request,
                    (AppContext) any);
            }

            result = xstream.fromXML(xmlReader);
        }
        };


    }
But while running i am getting this error
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid conditional statement
>   inside expectation block  at
>   com.hp.it.sbs.obligation.service.ObligationServiceImplMockTest_old$1.(ObligationServiceImplMockTest_old.java:2560)
>     at
>   com.hp.it.sbs.obligation.service.ObligationServiceImplMockTest_old.setExpectationsForOrchestration(ObligationServiceImplMockTest_old.java:2547)
>     at
>   com.hp.it.sbs.obligation.service.ObligationServiceImplMockTest_old.testRetrieveServiceObligationResponsesByServiceObligationRequests(ObligationServiceImplMockTest_old.java:169)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Can anyone answer on this . I am using the jmockit version 1.21

Answer (score 0):

It's just what the error message says: "Invalid conditional statement inside expectation block". That is, an expectation block is not allowed (by design) to have `if` statements (or any other statement containing a boolean condition).

Instead, the test should only contain the expectations it needs for the one specific scenario being tested.